# Why do people in Melbourne Victoria Australia get a public holiday for a horse race

Tags: australia, sports

Every year on the first tuesday of novemember there is a public holiday for the [Melbourne Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melbourne_Cup) the arcticle in wikipedia explains when it became a public holiday but not why.

> As early as 1865, Cup day was a half-holiday in Melbourne for public servants and bank officials. Various businesses also closed at
>   lunchtime. It took some years before the purpose of the declared
>   holiday was acknowledged in the Victoria Government Gazette. The
>   Gazette of 31 October 1873[63] announced that the following Thursday
>   (Cup Day) be observed as a bank and civil (public) service
>   holiday.[64]

Comment: In Adelaide SA, we get Adelaide Cup Day in March (thought the official Government name is the bland March Public Holiday).

Comment: Why do people in the U.S. get a holiday for [a dead 150 years now president](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln%27s_Birthday)? Because it is traditional to find an excuse for the holidays you give.

Comment: I'm after historical context and what made it important at the time @fred

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Public Record Office of Victoria](https://www.prov.vic.gov.au/about-us/our-blog/why-melbourne-cup-day-public-holiday) website, the secretary of the Victorian Racing Club, R.C. Bagot asked for it from the Chief Secretary’s Department:

> At that time provisions existed to allow for the proclamation of
>   special bank holidays under the Bank Holidays Act of that year and for
>   special civil service holidays under the Civil Service Act.  Although
>   these holidays were proclaimed by the Governor in Council and then
>   published in the Government Gazette, the task of preparing
>   documentation and making recommendations to the Governor was the
>   responsibility of the Chief Secretary’s Department.
>
> **On 30 October 1873, the Department prepared the necessary
>   documentation for the birthday of the Prince of Wales (9 November) to
>   be declared a special public holiday under the Civil Service Act. 
>   William Henry Odgers, the Under Secretary of the Department annotated
>   the margin with “Also the “Cup” Day sug[gests]s CS [Chief Secretary]”.**
>   This was duly approved by Chief Secretary James Goodall Francis.  The
>   documentation for the proclamation of Cup Day (6 November) was also
>   added to the Bank Holiday proclamation for the Prince’s birthday. But
>   this did not please everyone.  The file  containing these arrangements
>   (VPRS 3991/P0, unit  710, file 73/C15451) also contains a letter of
>   complaint from the Society for Promoting Morality.  It argued that the
>   proclamation of the public holiday may lead to young men “…contracting
>   the habit of “gambling”.”  It is unclear whether this had any effect
>   but a Cup Day was not proclaimed the following year.  By this time
>   Chief Secretary Francis had vacated his position and this might appear
>   to bear our Odgers’ annotation of the previous year that the holiday
>   was his idea.
>
> The 1874 Cup meeting was the last one to be run on a Thursday.  In
>   1875 it was moved to the second Tuesday of the month.  This meant the
>   Cup was to be run on 9 November, the Prince of Wales birthday.  As a
>   result civil service and bank holidays were gazetted.
>
> So, did the Victorian Racing Club (VRC) move the day for the Cup
>   meeting in 1875 to a Tuesday in order  to take advantage of a likely
>   public holiday?  Or was it soliciting a public holiday irrespective of
>   the day?  In this respect it is worth noting that in 1876, the
>   Secretary of the VRC, R.C. Bagot wrote to the Chief Secretary with the
>   following proposal: **“Will you make Tuesday 7th a holiday instead of
>   Thursday 9th.  Sir James informed me it was in your hand.”**  (VPRS
>   3992/P0, Unit 883, Item 76/K13038, File 76/K13126.)  **“Sir James” was
>   most likely Sir James McCulloch, the Premier at the time.**
>
> William Odgers subsequently annotated this item  to record that the
>   Chief Secretary had “seen” Mr Bagot but did not disclose any further
>   detail.  Subsequent to this meeting both of the 7th and 9th November
>   were Gazetted as Civil Service and Bank holidays. From then on the
>   precedent appears to have been set and a special public holiday for
>   the Cup was proclaimed annually. The extent of coverage of the act was
>   adjusted via these annual proclamations over time and legislation
>   specifically providing for a public holiday on the first Tuesday of
>   November was not enacted until the Public Holidays Act of 1993.